# Finding control on SharePoint page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Im trying to locate an SPDataSource control located on my SharePoint page.  I found the following code which probably works fine, I just don't know what to pass into it.

```
public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control Root, string Id)
{
    if (Root.ID == Id)
        return Root;

    foreach (Control Ctl in Root.Controls)
    {
        Control FoundCtl = FindControlRecursive(Ctl, Id);

        if (FoundCtl != null)
            return FoundCtl;
    }

    return null;
}
```

I don't know how to have it search the whole page or at the very least the ContentPlaceHolder that the control is in.

*edit*

Looks like I have a more rudimentary issue here.  Not sure how to explain but I'm not opening up the page before running my code.  I'm opening the site via the following:

```
using (SPWeb web = thisSite.Site.OpenWeb("/siteurl/,true))
```

So when I try to find the page below I'm getting Object reference not set to instance of object.

```
var page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
```

Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way, I'm in my infancy here so I'm just kind of stumbling along figuring stuff out!

Comment: Care to explain why are you trying to find a SPDataSource via code?

Comment: I have an event handler for a list that creates a site from a template, now I want it to update the SPDataSource on the template site with data it brings over from the list item.  Mainly, I'm looking to update the SelectCommand in the SPDataSource so I can filter the data.

Answer (score 1):

What you got is actually not SharePoint specific, it's c# asp.net.

Anyway, you could call it like this

```
var page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
var control = page; // or put the element you know exist that omit (is a parent) of the element you want to find
var myElement = FindControlRecursive(control, "yourelement");
```

Most likely you'll need to cast the return as well

```
var myElement = (TextBox)FindControlRecursive(control, "yourelement");
// or
var myElement = FindControlRecursive(control, "yourelement") as TextBox;
```

There are however more efficient ways to write such a method, here is one simple example

```
public static Control FindControlRecursive(string id)
{
    var page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
    return FindControlRecursive(page, id);
}

public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id)
{
    return root.ID == id ? root : (from Control c in root.Controls select FindControlRecursive(c, id)).FirstOrDefault(t => t != null);
}
```

Call it the same way as I suggested earlier.

If you are handling larger pages the methods above might be a bit slow, what you should do is aim for a method using generics instead. They are way faster than traditional methods.

Try this one

```
public static T FindControlRecursive<T>(Control control, string controlID) where T : Control
{
    // Find the control.
    if (control != null)
    {
        Control foundControl = control.FindControl(controlID);
        if (foundControl != null)
        {
            // Return the Control
            return foundControl as T;
        }
        // Continue the search
        foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
        {
            foundControl = FindControlRecursive<T>(c, controlID);
            if (foundControl != null)
            {
                // Return the Control
                return foundControl as T;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

You call it like this

```
var mytextBox = FindControlRecursive<TextBox>(Page, "mytextBox");
```

Comment: Edited my post, think I have a bigger issue preventing me from trying your code.